# Disable "pull to refresh" space on top of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I'd like to know if it's possible to disable the "pull to refresh" space on top of a collection view, when the user reaches the top of it.

This is the normal state:

[image]

And this is when I pull it down, there is this blank space that I'd like to avoid:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called bouncing.

and you can disable it either in editor

just select your CollectionView and under inspector you will find the bounces properties

disable them (or just what you want)

[image: inspector]

or programmatically

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.bounces = false
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `collectionView.bounces` and `collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical` to false.